# Multhreaded programming in C

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have been given an assignment. There is a dictionary of 25 files and each file has random text involving random IP addresses. The task is to find out and output the count of unique IP addresses among all files using the `pthread` library in C.

I think I have solved the race condition on count variable by mutual exclusion. But, still there is a bug and the code has different count value in each execution.

Here is the code, please suggest fixes for the bug:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

//declaring structure of arguments to give arguments to thread function
struct arg_struct
{
   char *arg1; //argument 1 : to pass directory name to thread function
   struct dirent *arg2;    //argument 2: to pass file name to thread function
};

//declaring structure of pointer which will point unique ip addresses
struct uniqueip
{
    char *ip;
};

struct filenames
{
    char full_filename[256];
};

struct uniqueip u[200];

int count=0;// global count variable stores total unique ip addresses.
void *ReadFile(void *thread_no);//thread declaration
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dir;   //directory stream
    FILE *file; //file stream
    struct dirent *ent; // directory entry structure
    char *line = NULL;  // pointer to
    size_t len = 1000;  //the length of bytes getline will allocate
    size_t read;

    char full_filename[256];    //will hold the entire file path with
                                 //file name to read

    int x=0;

    pthread_attr_t attr;
      int rc;
          long thread_no;
      void *status;
      void *ReadFile(void *thread_no);

      // check the arguments
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments supplied\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if(argc > 2)
    {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied\n");
        return -1;
    }

       struct arg_struct args;
       args.arg1 = argv[1];

       pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); // initializing mutex

       /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
       pthread_attr_init(&attr);
       pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
        // try to open the directory given by the argument
        if ((dir = opendir (argv[1])) != NULL)
        {
            /* print all the files and directories within directory */
            while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
            {

                // Check if the list is a regular file
                if(ent->d_type == DT_REG)
                {
                    //Get the number of files first so that we would know number
                    //of threads to be created
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }

        pthread_t thread[x];
        struct filenames filenames[x];
        thread_no=0;

        // try to open the directory given by the argument
            if ((dir = opendir (argv[1])) != NULL)
            {
        /* print all the files and directories within directory */
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
        {

            // Check if the list is a regular file
            if(ent->d_type == DT_REG)
            {
                // Create the absolute path of the filename
                snprintf(filenames[thread_no].full_filename, sizeof filenames[thread_no].full_filename, 
                "./%s/%s", argv[1], ent->d_name);
                //creating threads to read files
                args.arg2 = ent; //assigning file name to argument 2

                printf("main: creating thread %ld  %s \n", thread_no,ent->d_name);

                rc = pthread_create(&thread[thread_no], &attr, ReadFile, (void *) &args);
                if (rc)
                {
                         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
                         exit(-1);
                }
                thread_no++;
            }
        }
            // Close the directory structure
            closedir (dir);
        }
        else
        {
            /* could not open directory */
            perror ("");
            return -1;
        }

                   /* Free attribute and wait for the other threads*/
        pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
        for(thread_no=0; thread_no<x; thread_no++)
        {
             rc = pthread_join(thread[thread_no], &status);
                     if (rc)
             {
                printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
                exit(-1);
             }
             printf("Main: completed join with thread %ld having a status of %ld\n",thread_no,(long)status);
        }
        printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
            printf("total no. of unique ip addresses are %d\n",count-1);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
                return 0;
}



void *ReadFile(void *thread_no)
{  // in thread function
    struct filenames *my_data;
    my_data = (struct filenames *)thread_no;

    char full_filename[256];
    FILE *file;    //file stream
    char *line = NULL;
    char *split = NULL;
    size_t len = 1000;    // pointer to the length of bytes getline will allocate
    size_t read;
    const char s[2]=" "; //used as string split to get ip address
    char *token;
    int flag = 0,j;

    // open the file
    file = fopen(my_data -> full_filename, "r");
    // file was not able to be open

    if (file != NULL)
    {
    //     Print out each line in the file

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1)
     {
              split=line;
              token = strtok(split,s);

          pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);   
          if(count==0){
                  //locking mutex variable to avoid race condition
                  u[count].ip=malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
                  strcpy(u[count].ip,token);
                  printf("%d ------ %s\n",count,u[count].ip); 
                  free(u[count].ip);
                  count++;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // unlocking mutex
                //comparing recently received ip address to all the stored unique ip address.
                for(j=0;j<count;j++)
                {
                    if(!(strcmp(u[j].ip,token)))
                    {
                         break;
                    }
                    else
                    {     
                 if(j==count-1){                
                  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //locking mutex variable to avoid race condition
                  u[count].ip=malloc(sizeof(read));
                  strcpy(u[count].ip,token);
                  printf("%d ------ %s\n",count,u[count].ip);
                  count++;
                  free(u[count].ip);
                  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); // unlocking mutex
                  }
            }
                }
        }


     }

    fclose(file);
    pthread_exit((void*) thread_no);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several issues in this code.

You only ever create one instance of `arg_struct`, but you re-use it and pass it to every thread.  This means that by the time a thread starts, the value of the `arg_struct` you passed it may have changed.  You need to give each thread its own `arg_struct` - eg. you could declare an array of them alongside the `pthread_t` array:

```
pthread_t thread[x];
struct arg_struct args[x];
```

A similar problem exists with the `struct dirent *` pointer inside `arg_struct` - the data pointed to by the `struct dirent *` returned by `readdir()` may be overwritten by the next call to `readdir()` on the same directory stream.  There are a few ways to solve this, but one way is to replace the `char *arg1;` and `struct dirent *` in `arg_struct` with a buffer to hold the filename:

```
struct arg_struct
{
    char full_filename[256];    //will hold the entire file path with
                                 //file name to read
};
```

The main thread can then be changed to put the filename straight into the `arg_struct`:

```
snprintf(args[thread_no].full_filename, sizeof args[thread_no].full_filename, "./%s/%s", argv[1], ent->d_name);
```

In the `ReadFile()` function, this creates an array of one element and then tries to write to the (non-existent) second element, which has undefined behaviour:

```
char * argv[1];
argv[1]= my_data->arg1;
```

That code can be removed entirely, though - now that `main()` is constructing the full filename for the thread, the thread can just directly open it from the the `arg_struct`:

```
file = fopen(my_data->full_filename, "r");
```

(The thread doesn't need to worry about `argv[1]` at all anymore).

Your thread function is reading the shared `count` variable without holding the mutex - you need to lock the mutex before executing `if (count == 0)`, and don't unlock it until after the `for ()` loop (otherwise, you might get two threads deciding to add an IP to the same array location).

When you try to create a copy of the string you want to store, you aren't allocating enough space: `sizeof read` is always the fixed size of a `size_t` variable and isn't related to the size of the string you're copying.  You want:

```
u[count].ip = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
strcpy(u[count].ip, token);
```

You don't want to immediately free the `u[count].ip`, either: you need that string to stay allocated.  Remove the `free(u[count].ip);` lines.

---

There's some easy optimisations you could make, once you get it working.  For example, because `count` only increases and the `u[]` array is static below the value of `count`, you can lock the mutex, save a copy of `count` then unlock the mutex.  Loop up to the saved value of `count` - if you find the string then you can just move straight onto the next line of your input file.  It's only if you *don't* find the string that you need to re-lock the mutex, then continue from the saved count value up to the current count value (which might have increased in the meantime), adding the new string to the array (and incrementing `count`) if nececssary.

Comment: thanks for help...I changed the code as you said... but now i get segmentation fault! @caf

Comment: @caf...i change my code and uploaded..please have a look!

Comment: @VishleshPatel: You need to pass `&filenames[thread_no]` as the fourth argument to `pthread_create()`, since that's what the thread expects now.  You also should *not* be unlocking the mutex before the `for()` loop - the loop controlling expression reads `count`.  You need to keep the mutex locked the whole time until after the `for()` loop has finished.

Comment: `sizeof(token)` is wrong, it needs to be `strlen(token)` - this is not the same thing (you also need to fix the other place that you used `sizeof(read)`; and you still have the problem where you are calling `free(u[count].ip)` (in two places) when you shouldn't be - you need those strings to remain valid until the end of the program.

Comment: @caf...thanks a lot for help...now it's working fine....mutex should be handled properly!